# How to Login a User into my RESTFul Webservice for use with javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext

Tags: java, rest, security, java-ee-6

I am currently stuck at implementing security into my RESTFul Webservice.
I have found out that there is a SecurityContext which is easy to use and then again got stuck at putting my user information into it.

```
@GET
@Path("item/{item_id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Item getItem(@Context SecurityContext sc, @PathParam("item_id") Long id)
{

    if(!sc.isSecure())
        throw new SecurityException("You have to use a secure connection!");
    if(!sc.isUserInRole("admin"))
    {
        throw new SecurityException("You have to be an admin to access this information");
    }
    return itemFacade.find(id);
}
```

So my problem is that I need to write a Login for my Webservice but I don't know how to do so (so I can use it with the SecurityContext object). If there is no possibility to use the SecurityContext Object I would appreciate it if you could get me some links so I could work through them. 
Also it has to be up-to-date technology, meaning if it is possible without modifying the web.xml file and only managing this with Annotations, this would probably the best approach.

I am working with NetBeans 7.3, JavaEE6 and use GlassFish as Application Server.

Comment: Have you read through [this](http://www.butonic.de/2010/06/18/a-simple-jax-rs-security-context-example-in-glassfish/)?

Comment: Yes. That is also one part of my question. Because in that Tutorial, they use the web.xml file in the project to "secure" parts of the service, but I want to avoid that - if it's possible. I don't know which is the "newest" approach to secure a REST Service because things in Java change pretty fast and then you can find anything on the internet - new and old solutions. That's why I asked if there is a better way to achieve this, because I think it isn't clear if you put everything in the web.xml file!

Comment: Security is neither trivial, nor easy. You could implement a configuration-less solution using a `@WebFilter` annotated class and some custom coding, but its not going to be less work.

Comment: Well I know that it is never easy. I know that many things are done by annotations and class inheritance in java, so I was wondering if there is a possibility to inherit from a security-class and annotate it so the container uses it for authentification or something like that. But as it seems I have to do it with the web.xml way, because it seems the simplest solution so far. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What about leveraging the Java servlet session, storing user id as a session variable upon calling a login method and implementing your own infrastructure for checking identity and permissions? A clean approach could be performing checks by creating an interceptor and annotating methods that need to be checked.

Comment: So you mean that I work with the HttpSession-Object, get the Session, save the ID somewhere (with a Timeout) and associate everything the user does with it?

Comment: And when a user tries to access a proteced ressource, the interceptor decides whether he is privileged to do that or not

Comment: Yes, exactly, you can save the id as a session attribute, so as soon as a method is called the interceptor can evaluate it against privilege rules.

Answer (score 0):

For Authentication and authorization, you should consider using JAAS. The JAAS API consists of a set of Java packages designed for user authentication and authorization. It implements a Java version of the standard Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) framework and compatibly extends the Java 2 Platform's access control architecture to support user-based authorization. JAAS was first released as an extension package for JDK 1.3 and is bundled with JDK 1.4+. Because the JBossSX framework uses only the authentication capabilities of JAAS to implement the declarative role-based J2EE security model, this introduction focuses on only that topic.

JAAS authentication is performed in a pluggable fashion. This permits Java applications to remain independent from underlying authentication technologies and allows the JBossSX security manager to work in different security infrastructures. Integration with a security infrastructure can be achieved without changing the JBossSX security manager implementation. All that needs to change is the configuration of the authentication stack that JAAS uses.

Here are the tutorials for your further help:

http://www.kopz.org/public/documents/tomcat/jaasintomcat.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/java-jaas-form-based-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I am still unsure if there is'nt an easier approach, because when I look at the tutorials it looks like there is very much work to do. I wouldn't mind if there is already a ready to use implementation or a library in java itself which handles it.

Comment: @Kafioin Another simpler approach is to use ServletFilter. Write a filter to intercept all the requests to your service. And do the authentication there, if good forward the request to the servlet/service, else return 400 BAD REQUEST or similar error.

Comment: But still RestServices are Stateless. That's why I saw many implementations done via Tokens. I can ensure that there is a safe connection with the SecurityContext-Object, but I think that this may be too much overhead and not the best approach for a secure RestService. Still, thanks for your answer again :)